Skip job if previous haven't been done. Quartz.net
I have some job. It runs every 5 seconds. But if job will take more than 5 seconds, I need to cancel next job and run next job on schedule after this is done.
Job class:
public class LoggerJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggerJob> _logger;
    
    public LoggerJob(ILogger<LoggerJob> logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }
    
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    { 
        //some logic here
        _logger.LogInformation($"Log Job: at {DateTime.Now} and Jobtype: {context.JobDetail.JobType}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Schedule class start method:
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(cancellationToken);
        Scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;


        _jobsMetadata?.ForEach(async jobMetadata =>
        {

            IJobDetail jobDetail = CreateJob(jobMetadata);

            ITrigger trigger = CreateTrigger(jobMetadata);

            await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger, cancellationToken);

        });
        await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
    }

I tried smth like this, but it's just blocks other job executing and they waiting until lock:
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (!_isRunning)
            {
                //somelogic
                _logger.LogInformation($"Log Job: at {DateTime.Now} and Jobtype: {context.JobDetail.JobType}");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Job canceled at {DateTime.Now}");
                context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.Put("cancel", true);
            }
        }
        

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Using a lock to control job execution can block other jobs, creating inefficiencies. Instead, consider utilizing asynchronous programming with cancellation tokens for a more efficient solution. By setting a timeout for job execution, you can cancel it if it exceeds a specified time limit. Here's how you can adapt your code to implement this approach:
public class LoggerJob : IJob
{
private readonly ILogger<LoggerJob> _logger;
private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

public LoggerJob(ILogger<LoggerJob> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    // Set a timeout for the job execution
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    // Execute the job logic asynchronously
    var jobTask = ExecuteJobLogic(context);

    // Wait for either the job completion or the timeout
    var completedTask = Task.WhenAny(jobTask, timeoutTask);

    // Handle the completed task
    return completedTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task == jobTask)
        {
            // Job completed before timeout, cancel the timeout
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            // Timeout occurred, log cancellation
            _logger.LogInformation($"Job canceled due to timeout at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    });
}

private async Task ExecuteJobLogic(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    try
    {
        // Your job logic goes here
        _logger.LogInformation($"Log Job: at {DateTime.Now} and Jobtype: {context.JobDetail.JobType}");
        await Task.Delay(/* Your job logic */);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions thrown by the job logic
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error executing job");
    }
  }
}

